# EXCEL VBA: CONCAT 3 columns from multiple rows when value from a cell is found on another excel file

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

To my head it seems very complicated, so excuse me for writing too much.

In excel file #1 the A column corresponds to a "type" and the B column to the needed result. (see picture 1).

[image]

In excel file #2 column A has the "type" again, columns B, C & D are the columns of interest.(see picture 2).

[image]

I need to concatenate columns B, C, D from #2 to #1 when the "type" from #1 is found on the same row and add with a line break all the next rows that have the same "type" in #2.

Between columns B and C should be a "["and between columns C and D should be a "]" like shown.

When ":" is in column B we don't want to concatenate and skip to the next one.

I've managed to do it step-step filtering and copying but it's not efficient when someone has to deal with large data.

I'm using already these functions:

!as a column to concatente everything
E2=A2&"["&B2&"]"&C2)

!another column to filter the values i need
F2=IF(LEFT(E2;2)=":[";"";E2)

!then concatenate without blanks
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);TRUE;F2:F26)

I hope I didn't confuse you a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT(FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2,3},E$2:E$10&"[",F$2:F$10&"]",G$2:G$10&" "),(D$2:D$10=A2)*(E$2:E$10<>":"),"")))," ",CHAR(10))
```

In Excel 2019 it would be an array-entered formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCAT(IF((D$2:D$10=A2)*(E$2:E$10<>":"),E$2:E$10&"["&F$2:F$10&"]"&G$2:G$10&" "),""))," ",CHAR(10))
```

Comment: Looks awesome, but I use excel 2019 (forgot to mention that unfortunately ), so I don't have "FILTER" function available.

Comment: @CptCode, see my edited answer to include the CSE-entered Excel 2019 option.

Comment: Wow, you're very fast! I tried to edit my previous answer with this:
Looks awesome, but I use excel 2019 (forgot to mention that unfortunately ), so I don't have FILTER function available.
Another thing I forgot to mention was that the "type" consists of an alphanumeric string like "ABC-D10F" (I oversimplified my example ), so function CHOOSE can't work as well.
Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @CptCode, that is not a problem for the answer I put together. It can handle alphanumeric strings just fine and has nothing to do with the `CHOOSE()` function which is only there as a remnant from the `FILTER()` function. WHile it would even work now, we can even remove it and use the `&` to concatenate columns.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, we are definitely on the correct path, but when I tried, it did not work:
https://pasteboard.co/g2Gzx2LRmsJa.png

Comment: @CptCode, you need to confirm it through Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just enter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine the `=CONCAT` function with some `IF()` statements.

CONCAT is comma separated, so try for example `=CONCAT(A1, "[", B1, "]")` etc.

You can combine that with the IF requirements that you have to match between cells and return what you need.

Comment: The IFs are the hard part .
Please check my comments to @Jvd, they have additional info.
Thanks for your answer!